# Precise rank of a sparse integer matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Consider a large sparse rectangular integer matrix. Is there a way to compute its exact rank that is better in terms of speed and/or memory usage compared to a dense matrix?

Comment: I think there are techniques using the so-called block Wiedemann approach. [This paper](https://perso.ens-lyon.fr/gilles.villard/BIBLIOGRAPHIE/PDF/valence.pdf) may be relevant and/or contain relevant references. I do not know the literature on this subject very well, so this may also not be the most relevant paper.